# Denotational semantics, proving that fixed point iteration results in the least fixed point

Tags: haskell, denotational-semantics

I'm working through the Haskell wikibook section on [denotational semantics](https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Haskell/Denotational_semantics) and I'm kind of stuck on this exercise:

> Prove that the fixed point obtained by fixed point iteration starting
>   with [image] is also the least one, that it is smaller than any other
>   fixed point. (Hint: [image] is the least element of our cpo and g is
>   monotone).

Where the following statements define the core of the concepts leading up to the exercise (I think):

[image]

[image]

[image]

where f is the factorial function and is shown to be the fixed-point of g, given that g is continuous.

I think I basically understand the part where it is shown that g(f) = f but I don't really know what to make of the exercise. From what I understand, the factorial function f is the least-fixed point (with least based on the [image] operator) but it's not at all clear to me what it means (intuitively) to compare functions with [image], let alone how I would find fixed points other than the least-fixed point shown in the example.

I understand that [image] is less than everything else, and I understand that since g(x) is monotonic, if I apply it to two things, where one is less than the other, the results will still obey this ordering.

I think I would start the proof with taking some function f' and assuming [image]. If that is the case, through the monotonic property of g I can show that [image]. If I can then show that necessarily g(f') = g(f) or f' = f I think the proof is complete but I have no idea how to show that.

Comment: I believe this kind of questions are much more suited to [computerscience.SE] than to StackOverflow.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Let `x` be the sup/least upper bound of the sequence `bot, g(bot), g(g(bot)), ...`. Let `y` be any fixed point of `g` (monotonic). We want to prove that `x <= y`.

By induction on the number of iterations, it's easy to see that every element in the sequence is `<= y`. Indeed, it trivially holds for `bot`, and if `z` is `<= y` by monotonicity we get `g(z) <= g(y) = y`.

So, `y` is an upper bound of the sequence. But `x` is the least, so `x <= y`. QED.